# find lowest qualification of a student from the main database

Tags: php, postgresql

I have a student database where each student has multiple records based on all of his/her qualification.
I want to find the lowest qualification of each student respectively.

I have tried a SQL query by grouping according to qualifications, but that results in all the records.

```
select student_id,qualification
from student
group by qualification
order by qualification ASC
```

For EX: Original Table

```
1 SSC 50
1 HSC 60
2 SSC 80
2 HSC 60
2 Grad 50
3 HSC 70
4 SSC 70
4 Diploma 70
```

Expected Result

```
1 SSC 50
2 SSC 80
3 HSC 70
4 SSC 70
```

Comment: If you could split `qualification` into `qualification` and  `value`, then it becomes a simpler matter.

Comment: could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: can you show your db structure

Comment: Convert the qualification into numbers. `SSC 50` would be `1050` and `HSC 50` would be `1250` similarly `HSC 60` would be `1260`. For `Diploma 50`: `1350` and `Diploma 70`: `1370`. `ASC` can not recognise that `HSC` is higher education and `SSC` is secondary.

Comment: Qualification is a varchar with subject code and qualification?

Comment: create table student(id char 50, qualf char 10, percentage numeric(2,0) primary key (id,qualf))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you separate the data, into a qualifications field, and a score field, then it's a simple matter of using `MIN()`. You have to `GROUP BY` on all fields in the select, so we can find the lowest qualifications with `MIN()`, then join that result in to get the other relevant columns, like `qualifications`.

I assume `Diplomia` is not a valid qualification?

```
create table students (
  student_id int,
  qualification varchar(128),
  score int
);

insert into students (student_id, qualification, score)
values
(1, 'SSC', 50),
(1, 'HSC', 60),
(2, 'SSC', 80),
(2, 'HSC', 60),
(2, 'Grad', 50),
(3, 'HSC', 70),
(4, 'SSC', 70),
(4, 'Diploma', 70);
```

Then a simple query, with `MIN()` - keep in mind that you always have to use `GROUP BY` when using an aggregate function, like `MIN()`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM students 
JOIN (
  SELECT student_id, MIN(score) as score
  FROM students
  GROUP BY student_id
) min_score USING (student_id, score)
WHERE qualification <> 'Diploma'
```

Output becomes

```
student_id  score   qualification
1           50      SSC
2           50      Grad
3           70      HSC
4           70      SSC
```

See this [live demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7GgYddHGpTJ9qS1phpR6be/1).

Comment: is there a way wher i can fetch the marks of the lowest qualification as well? Because i tried adding the field to my query  but it gave me multiple records

Comment: You can probably separate logic, as marks is calculated from the score. Keep in mind you need to `GROUP BY` all selected fields for a proper result.